# Sidemenu not closing - Xamarin.iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to implement a side menu in Xamarin.iOS by using this [component](https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/sidebarnavigation) and this [example](https://github.com/alexrainman/MvvmCross.FlyOutMenu/tree/master/FlyOutMenu.Touch).
Everything worked fine except the part where I want to close the Side Menu.

Now it works like this: I can open the side menu either by using the LeftButton from NavigationItem or the finger swipe. But I can't close it with either of those two methods.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening? What am I missing?

See also code below.

HomeView

```
public partial class HomeView : MvxViewController
{
    public HomeView() : base("HomeView", null)
    {
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();
        // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        CGRect screenRect = UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds;
        NavigationController.View.Frame = new CGRect(0, 0, screenRect.Width, screenRect.Height);

        var app = UIApplication.SharedApplication.Delegate as AppDelegate;
        NavigationItem.SetLeftBarButtonItem(
            new UIBarButtonItem(UIImage.FromBundle("menu"),
                                UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, (sender, e) =>
                                {
                                    app.SidebarController.ToggleMenu();
                                }), true);
    }
```

RootView

```
public partial class RootView : MvxViewController
{
    public RootViewModel RootViewModel
    {
        get { return (RootViewModel)ViewModel; }
        set { ViewModel = value; }
    }

    public RootView() : base("RootView", null)
    {
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();
        // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        if (ViewModel == null)
            return;

        var app = UIApplication.SharedApplication.Delegate as AppDelegate;
        app.SidebarController = new SidebarController(this,
                                                  CreateViewFor(RootViewModel.Home, false), CreateViewFor(RootViewModel.Menu, true));
        app.SidebarController.MenuWidth = 220;
        app.SidebarController.ReopenOnRotate = false;
        app.SidebarController.MenuLocation = MenuLocations.Left;
    }

    public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning()
    {
        base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning();
        // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
    }

    private UIViewController CreateViewFor(IMvxViewModel viewModel, bool navBarHidden)
    {
        var controller = new UINavigationController();
        var screen = this.CreateViewControllerFor(viewModel) as UIViewController;
        controller.PushViewController(screen, false);
        controller.NavigationBarHidden = navBarHidden;
        return controller;
    }
```

Comment: I do not know what is wrong with your code. But I'm using Sidebar Navigation in my project and it is working very well. If you want, I can post my code

Comment: You're using it with MVVMCross also?

Comment: As I continued to investigate this, I discovered that the RootViewController is on top the other two controllers (Menu and Home ViewControler) and it does blocking all the interaction/events on those two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix the strange behavior by adding the row below in ViewDidLoad() from RootView.cs:

```
View.Frame = new CGRect(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

For some reason it looks like the view from RootViewController was above the other two and this is the only way I managed to make it work. If anyone have a better solution, please add your answer and I'll try it. What I've done looks more like a workaround.

@HeisenBerg There is one difference between our projects, I'm using MVVMCross, which changes a bit more the flow between screens. But thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I've implemented Sidebar Navigation in my app and its working very well.

RootViewController.cs

```
public class RootViewController : UIViewController
{
    UIStoryboard _storyboard;

    // the sidebar controller for the app
    public SidebarController LeftSidebarController { get; private set; }

    // the navigation controller
    public NavigationController NavController { get; private set; }

    // the storyboard
    public override UIStoryboard Storyboard {
        get {
            if (_storyboard == null)
                _storyboard = UIStoryboard.FromName ("Main", null);
            return _storyboard;
        }
    }

    public RootViewController () : base (null, null)
    {

    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad ();

        var programController = (CareProgramController)Storyboard.InstantiateViewController ("careProgramController"); // This is the menu..
        var leftMenuController = (LeftMenuController)Storyboard.InstantiateViewController ("leftMenuController"); // This is the initial ViewController
        NavController = new NavigationController ();
        NavController.PushViewController (programController, false);
        LeftSidebarController = new SidebarController (this, NavController, leftMenuController) {
            HasShadowing = false,
            MenuWidth = 280,
            MenuLocation = MenuLocations.Left
        };
    }
}
```

BaseViewController.cs

```
public class BaseViewController : UIViewController
{

    // provide access to the sidebar controller to all inheriting controllers
    protected SidebarNavigation.SidebarController SidebarController {
        get {
            return (UIApplication.SharedApplication.Delegate as AppDelegate).RootViewController.LeftSidebarController;
        }
    }

    // provide access to the navigation controller to all inheriting controllers
    protected NavigationController NavController {
        get {
            return (UIApplication.SharedApplication.Delegate as AppDelegate).RootViewController.NavController;
        }
    }

    // provide access to the storyboard to all inheriting controllers
    public override UIStoryboard Storyboard {
        get {
            return (UIApplication.SharedApplication.Delegate as AppDelegate).RootViewController.Storyboard;
        }
    }

    public BaseViewController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    {
    }


    public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad ();
        SetupNavigationBar ();
        SetDrawerToogle ();
    }

    void SetupNavigationBar ()
    {
        if (NavController != null) {
            NavController.NavigationBar.BarTintColor = AZConstants.PrimaryColor;
            NavController.NavigationBar.Translucent = false;
            NavController.NavigationBar.TintColor = UIColor.White;
            NavController.NavigationBar.BarStyle = UIBarStyle.Black;
        }
    }

    void SetDrawerToogle ()
    {
        NavigationItem.SetLeftBarButtonItem (
            new UIBarButtonItem (UIImage.FromFile ("ic_menu_white.png").ImageWithRenderingMode (UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal)
                , UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain
                , (sender, args) => {
                    SidebarController.ToggleMenu ();
                }), true);
    }
}
```

Now all the ViewControllers in my app extends from BaseViewController so it'll have a navigation drawer

AppDelegate.cs

```
public class AppDelegate : UIApplicationDelegate
{
    // class-level declarations

    public RootViewController RootViewController { get { return Window.RootViewController as RootViewController; } }

    public override UIWindow Window
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions)
    {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        // If not required for your application you can safely delete this method
        UIApplication.SharedApplication.SetStatusBarStyle(UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent, true);

        GotoRootViewController();
        return true;
    }

    public void GotoRootViewController()
    {
        Window = new UIWindow(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);
        //Window.RootViewController.DismissViewController(true, null);
        //If you have defined a root view controller, set it here:
        Window.RootViewController = new RootViewController();

        // make the window visible
        Window.MakeKeyAndVisible();
    }
```